# Pyspark: How to parallelize multi gz file processing in HDFS

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, hdfs, gzip

I have many `gz` files stored in 20 nodes `HDFS` cluster that need to be aggregated by columns. The `gz` files are very large (1GByte each and 200 files in total).
The data format is key value with 2 column values: `['key','value1','value2']`, and needs to be grouped by key with aggregation by column: `sum(value1)`, `count(value2)`.

**The data is already sorted by key and each gz files have exclusive key values.**

For example:

```
File 1:
k1,v1,u1
k1,v2,u1
k2,v2,u2
k3,v3,u3
k3,v4,u4

File 2:
k4,v5,u6
k4,v7,u8
k5,v9,v10

File 3:
k6,...
...
...

File 200:
k200,v200,u200
k201,v201,u201
```

I firstly parse the date and convert the data into `(key, list of (values))` structure. The parser output will be like this:

```
parser output
(k1,[v1,u1])
(k1,[v2,u1])
(k2,[v2,u2])
(k3,[v3,u3])
(k3,[v4,u4])
```

Then group by key values using `reduceByKey` function, which is more efficient than `groupByKey` function.

```
reducer output:
(k1,[[v1,u1],[v2,u1])
(k2,[[v2,u2]])
(k3,[[v3,u3],[v4,u4]])
```

Then aggregate the columns using process function:

```
process 
(k1, sum([v1,v2], len([u1,u3])))
(k2, sum([v2], len([u2])))
(k3, sum([v3,v4], len([u3,u4])))
```

Here is the sample code for the process

```py
import pyspark
from pyspark import SparkFiles

def parser(line):
    try:
        key,val=line.split('\t)
        return (key,[val1,val2])
    except:
        return None

def process(line):
    key,gr= line[0],line[1]
    vals=zip(*gr)

    val1=sum(vals[0])
    val2=len(vals[1])
    return ('\t'.join([key,val1,val2]))

sc = pyspark.SparkContext(appName="parse")
logs=sc.textFile("hdfs:///home/user1/*.gz")
proc=logs.map(parser).filter(bool).reduceByKey(lambda acc,x: acc+x).map(process)
proc.saveAsTextFile('hdfs:///home/user1/output1')
```

I think this code does not fully utilize the spark cluster. I like to optimize the code to fully utilize the processing considering.

**1. What is the best way to handle gz files in HDFS and Pyspark?** -- how to fully distribute the gz file processing to the entire cluster?

**2. How to fully utilize all the CPUs in each node?** for aggregation and parsing process

Comment: Load the files to the dataframe of spark fisrt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least a couple of things you should consider:

1. If you are using YARN, the number of executors and the cores per executor that you assign to your spark app. They can be controlled by --num-executors and --executor-cores. If you are not using YARN, your scheduler will probably have a similar mechanism to control parallelism, try looking for it.
2. The number of partitions in your DataFrame, which directly impacts the parallelism in your job. You can control that with [repartition](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.repartition) and/or [coalesce](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce).

Both can limit the cores used by the job and hence the use of the cluster. Also, take into account that more CPUs employed will not necessarily mean better performance (or execution times). That will depend on the size of your cluster and the size of the problem, and I don't know about any easy rule to decide that. For me it usually comes down to experiment with different configurations and see which one has better performance.